# CSS style isn't showing on browser, but inspector/devtools says it's being applied

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, base64

I'm downloading a template with embedded javascript and CSS that's encoded in base64 and showing it in a modal. However, for some reason almost none of the styles are showing, despite the chrome inspector/devtools showing they are being applied without issues (and the computed section shows they aren't being overriden by anything). I've never seen this before, any ideas?

Edit: I'm suspecting this has something to do with the browser not rendering it correctly. Is there someway to trigger a render with javascript, or something like that?

Here is what the template looks like:

```
<div class="template">
  <p id="myparagraph">Some text</p>
</div>
<style>
#myparagraph {
  color: red
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try this #myparagraph {color: red !important;}

Comment: Since this works, you will need to provide more to your question https://jsfiddle.net/tbfku0do/

Comment: Exactly, this works everywhere else without issues. That's why I have no idea of what is going on.

Comment: Works when [statically loaded](http://dabblet.com/gist/a2d6856e2e1ad764bec4) and [dynamically loaded](https://jsfiddle.net/5rs1oq5s/) on the old-ass versions of Firefox and Chrome I have at work... Gonna need full src of the resulting html to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this once or twice before, I would say try the !important to see if that makes a difference (though I strongly advise against using !important, it can lead to complex style issues later on). I would also trying pressing Shift + F5 and doing a hard refresh, in order to make sure the browser isn't caching anything in an odd way.

Comment: Tried it...nothing yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the stylesheet before your html and add `!important` at the end of your css value to override any other css style on that element.

Comment: Chrome Inspector shows the stye is being applied, regardless of the !important statement. it isn't a problem of a rule being overriden. It's just not showing visibly when rendered.

Comment: I need to see the whole HTML document to solve this issue. You probably have the wrong document structure, doctype, or anything.

Comment: Removing the need for the browser hoisting gets a +1, but `!important` is **never** a good solution unless you're hacking a 3rd party widget from _outside_ the widget, so net of 0 on this one.

Comment: Er, also, fairly sure `#` selectors have the highest specificity of pretty much all selectors, so the only way to override it (outside of cascade, which means something lower in the document is using the same selector) without `!important` would be something like `.class #id`- basically meaning the odds of your `!important` doing anything that you actually want is practically nil